# Sliding a UIViewController to pop - as in the Readability app

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to emulate the sliding UIViewController as seen in the Readability app. You can drag a page to the right and it pops the current view off the stack to go back to parent UIViewController with a sliding animation as in the image: the right-most view was on the top and is being dragged right-wards showing the original table on the left.

[image: view being slided to the right]

I've tried a few of the slidingUIViewController solutions such as ECSlidingViewController but they try to emulate the Facebook/Path behaviour of partially sliding a slidingUIViewController on top of another which is not what Readability does.

I've also tried a standard horizontally scrolling UIScrollView but scrolls like the pages are joined at the sides, as opposed to sliding one view over another.

Does anyone know how they did this?

Comment: Isn't this what UIPageViewController is designed for? It will do this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished in few steps. I'm not going to write down all the code you need to write in order to do it, but just the steps you need to take. I will use a master-details terminology where the master view is the one from which you want to present a details view and the details view is of course the one at the top of the navigation stack.

When you want to present the detail view:

1) create an instance of the UIViewController that handles the interactions with the detailView. On iOS 5+ you can store this instance in the childrenViewControllers @property on the master's viewController. If you support a lower OS you should store the instance in an ivar.

2) set the detailView's frame to be outside the screen's bounds; add to detailView a shadow for graphical purposes. Finally add the detailView as a subview of the masterView.

3) (optional) add a pan gesture recognizer to the detailView in order to allow the user to swipe the view back and dismiss it.

4) animate the detailView in the screen's bounds. Make sure the interactions with the view below are disabled (be careful not to disable also the interactions with the detailsView!)

When you want to dismiss the detail view:

1) animate the detailView outside the screen's bounds.

2) remove it from it's superview and delete the reference to it's viewController.

3) re-enable the user interaction with the master view.